# Copy an paste VBA code making source page flash while active

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Import_New()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D7:AY13").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D7:AY13").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D26:AY32").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D26:AY32").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D42:AY48").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D42:AY48").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D57:AY63").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D57:AY63").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D73:AY79").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D73:AY79").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D88:AY94").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D88:AY94").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D104:AY110").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D104:AY110").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D119:AY125").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D119:AY125").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D135:AY141").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D135:AY141").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D150:AY156").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D150:AY156").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D166:AY172").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D166:AY172").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D181:AY187").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D181:AY187").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D197:AY203").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D197:AY203").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D212:AY218").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D212:AY218").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D228:AY234").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D228:AY234").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D243:AY249").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D243:AY249").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D259:AY265").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D259:AY265").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D274:AY280").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D274:AY280").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("D290:AY296").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New HR072").Range("D290:AY296").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
        
        OpenBook.Close False
        
    End If
End Sub
```

Wasn't expecting the flashing, is there a better way of achieving this

Comment: Have you tried `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

Comment: where would I add that?

Comment: Since you are just copying values you can directly set the values instead of using the clipboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the flashing going on, you can use

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Don't forget to use

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

at the end of your code.

What you can also use if this is a re-occuring thing, is using a function like so

```
Sub yourSub()
    improvePerformance True
    'do your code
    improvePerformance False
End Sub
Function improvePerformance(Optional Yes As Boolean = True) As Boolean
    With Application
    If Yes Then
      .ScreenUpdating = False
      .DisplayStatusBar = False
'      .Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'causes too many rewrites/extra time needed in code, copy pasting as value reduces plenty of time regarding this
      .EnableEvents = False
      .EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
    Else
      .ScreenUpdating = True
      .DisplayStatusBar = True
'      .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
      .EnableEvents = True
      .EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    End If
    End With
End Function
```

Regardless it might also be good to put your sheet in a variable to have a better readability:

```
Dim ws As WorkSheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New HR072")
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The function works a treat, thank you

Comment: You're welcome, as a tip: if your code would throw an error and you stop it, then the Function needs to be called again with False to set it back to its original state. So either have a sub in your personal to turn improvePerformance to False or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Copying values directly

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Import_New()

    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim wbBook As Workbook, wsBook As Worksheet
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, ar, i As Long
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", _
                 FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
    
    ' ranges
    ar = Array(7, 26, 42, 57, 73, 88, 104, 119, 135, 150, 166, _
              181, 197, 212, 228, 243, 259, 274, 290)
              
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
    
        Set wbBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen, ReadOnly:=True)
        Set wsBook = wbBook.Sheets(1)
        Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New HR072")
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
            ' expand to 7 rows col D:AY
            wsCopy.Cells(ar(i), "D").Resize(7, 48).Value = wsBook.Cells(ar(i), "D").Resize(7, 48).Value
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        wbBook.Close False
        MsgBox "Copied from " & FileToOpen, vbInformation
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```